# Exception handling in return value methods

Tags: c#

I'm working on a method that should follow this logic:

- Prompt the user to enter a number into the console
- Try to convert the input to an integer

  - If successful, return the integer
  - If unsuccessful, write the error message to console and restart the method

Here's what I have:

```
static int GetPlayers()
{
    int players = 0;

    Console.Write("How many people are playing?");

    try
    {
        players = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message + "\n" +
            "----------");
        GetPlayers();
    }

    return players;
}
```

The problem is simple, "not all code paths return a value." I can get it to do what I want, but it's going to have a couple ugly conditional statements that reflect how much of an amateur I am. I'm looking for an elegant, professional-grade solution to help me learn how to properly handle this type of logical sequence in the future.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out players)?Console.Write(players):"something cool"`

Comment: This code does not produce that error for me. The problem must be somewhere else. That said, it is usually better to use a loop than recursion to repeat something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `return` the result of  the second call of the method. If you just call the method without returning the value, the result will be `0` (if an error has been made).

You also could do `players = GetPlayers()` which I think it's more elegant because the method will have only *one way out*.

```C#
static int GetPlayers()
{
    int players = 0;

    Console.Write("How many people are playing?");

    try
    {
        players = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message + "\n" +
            "----------");
       return GetPlayers(); // return the result
    }

    return players;
}
```

The usage will look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var players = GetPlayers();
    Console.WriteLine("Players count: " + players);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output is like following:

```
How many people are playing?s 
Input string was not in a correct format.
----------How many people are playing?9
Players count: 9
```

Comment: @Hiimmas tested again `100%` that it works. Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Strange. The first time I tried it by simply putting the return in front of the GetPlayers(); and it didn't acknowledge it as a return path, giving me the same error message. I copied your code the second time and pasted it in without an errors though. I must have made a mistake somewhere. Sorry! And thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop and only return once players is set correctly.

```
static int GetPlayers()
{
    int? players;

    Console.Write("How many people are playing?");

    while (players == null)
    {
      try
      {
          players = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.Write(e.Message + "\n" + "----------");
      }
    }

    return players.Value;
}
```

Comment: /facepalm I had a feeling it was going to be something very simple. Now I'm running into "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I know I could avoid it by using an initial assignment of 0 and using that as the condition in the while loop, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Change return players to return players.Value

Answer (score 1):

The exceptional code path doesn't return a value, the compiler notices that.  It is a bug, never uncommon when you catch exceptions.  You are usually ahead by not assuming that there's anything exceptional about the user typing something wrong.  Besides, it isn't the only thing that you ought to check, you are not going to be happy about -1 or 3000 players either.

Just create an endless loop that you escape from when you got a correct entry.  Like this:

```
    static int GetPlayers(int max = 10) {
        for (;;) {
            Console.Write("Number of players: ");
            int players;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out players)) {
                if (players > 0 && players <= max) return players;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("  Oops, please type a number between 1 and " + max.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Some programmers find `for (;;)` grating, I'm not one of them.  You can use `while (true)` if you hate it.